# unable to execute jar file(consists dependencies), which is build from gradle

Tags: gradle, dependencies

i am very new to gradle, i was trying to build a java file which is dependent on other jar file. It is building properly but when i try to execute it, it is giving "NoClassDefinitionFoundError".

my build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin : 'java'


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Hey'
    }
}


dependencies
{
compile files('lib/BuildBasicJavaProject.jar') ------line A
}
```

if i remove the above **line A** then it is not even building the project.
if i keep that **line A** then it is building properly and producing the jar file, but when i execute it using ,

```
java -jar jarfilename.jar
```

then it is giving me a NoClassDefinitionFoundError.

Where do i need to specify the dependents path while running the jar file??

May be its a basic doubt but i wasted 2 days already in it, i tried giving 
1) absolute path of the dependency file

2) adding the following line,

```
runtime files('lib/BuildBasicJavaProject.jar')
```

But did not succeed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your goal? Just run the code via Gradle? Create a standalone executable Jar? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First welcome to Gradle world.
Your Gradle scripts seems to be correct. When you have a dependency, one jar depends on another like in your case at compile time you define compile time dependency like you did. So if you need this jar to run it you need runtime dependency, in your case. But Gradle automatically put all your compile time dependencies to be runtime dependencies. So you do not need to specify them explicitly.

So why then your code does not working?

The classpath (-cp) option is **ignored** if using the -**jar** option. So you can not specify dependent jar using -cp when type jar.So you have to write If you are on Windows

```
java -cp myJar.jar;.\lib\BuildBasicJavaProject.jar Hey
```

or use (:) and slashes(/) for Linux.

Where **Hey** is the full-quallified name of your main class, which have to be defind in the Manifest.

So if your class Hey is in the package:**com.alabala.dev** and it's name is **Hey** it's full qualified name is com.alabala.dev.Hey. So you have to tell Gradle

```
mainClassName = "com.alabala.dev.Hey"
```

So now Gradle put it in the manifest and when you are trying to load this jar in the JVM, she will know that to start it, she have to execute com.alabala.dev.Hey.

What is **cp** and why you have to specify it? Said with simple word cp is classpath - directories and archives in which JVM searches when want to load something. So here there is nothing linekd with Gradle it is Java.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to specify dependency jar(s) as a part of classpath, when you are executing your jar.
Something along these these lines:

```
java -cp myJar.jar:./lib/BuildBasicJavaProject.jar my.package.MyMainClass
```

Bare in mind that classpath delimiters are different on different platforms (: is for *nix based systems).

Comment: Hey sean, thanks for your early reply. But the method you suggested is not working. Following is my command and output i got. 
     java -jar BuildDependenciesJava.jar -cp  .\lib\BuildBasicJavaProject.jar Hey
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tesco/Hello
        at Hey.main(Hey.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tesco.Hello
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: You don't need -jar part, afaik. Just put them both on the classpath. (Besides that, -jar option will only work if you have a proper manifest file in your jar). Also, you need to supply full package, not just the  name of the main class.